# Overlapping in Bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, bar-chart

In this function we are fixing position of values on the plot, the problem is when Minutes played are equel 0.0 then this number on the plot overlapping the club name due to this number relies in the bar length. Example of overlapping problem is attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0uvU.png).
The function where calculation happens:

```
    for idx in df_single_stat.index:
            value = df_single_stat.loc[idx, stat_column_name]
            # y = len(df_single_stat) - idx - 1
            if df_single_stat.loc[idx, "Names"] == player_name_visuals:
                if stat_column_name.startswith("Minutes Played"):
                    ax.text(value + 0.002, index[-idx - 1], r"$\bf {:.0f}$".format(value), color="black", va="center")
                else:
                    ax.text(value + 0.002, index[-idx - 1], r"$\bf {:.2f}$".format(value), color="black", va="center")
            else:
                if stat_column_name.startswith("Minutes Played"):
                    ax.text(value + 0.002, index[-idx - 1], " {:.0f}".format(value), color="black", va="center")
            else:
                ax.text(value + 0.002, index[-idx - 1], " {:.2f}".format(value), color="black", va="center")
            ax.text(ax.get_xlim()[1] * 0.02, index[-idx - 1], df_single_stat.loc[idx, "Club"], color="black", va="center", fontsize=7)
  
    ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    ax.tick_params(axis="y", length=0)
```

Thank you so much for your time ad help

I tried plenty of times different solutions. The optimal one was when the Minutes played are equel 0.0 then on that individual bar line this number moves righter to avoid overlapping with Club name. But the proble is that somehow that rule applied to whole plot that shouldn't happen.The example of that solution:

```
spacing = 0.013  # Adjust the spacing as needed

for idx in df_single_stat.index:
    value = df_single_stat.loc[idx, stat_column_name]
    y = index[-idx - 1]  # Use 'y' to determine the vertical position of the bar/label
    
    if df_single_stat.loc[idx, "Names"] == player_name_visuals:
        if stat_column_name.startswith("Minutes Played"):
            if value > 0.1:  # Handle non-zero minutes played separately
                ax.text(value + 0.002, y, r"$\bf {:.0f}$".format(value), color="black", va="center")
            else:  # For zero minutes played, plot a bar at the end of the club name and add "0" label
                club_name = df_single_stat.loc[idx, "Club"]
                club_name_width = ax.text(0, 0, club_name, fontsize=7).get_window_extent(renderer=fig.canvas.get_renderer()).width
                ax.barh(y, 0.001, left=club_name_width + spacing, color="white", edgecolor="black")
                ax.text(club_name_width + 2 * spacing, y, "0", color="black", va="center", ha="left")
        else:
            ax.text(value + spacing, y, " {:.2f}".format(value), color="black", va="center")
    else:
        if stat_column_name.startswith("Minutes Played"):
            if value > 0.1:  # Handle non-zero minutes played separately
                ax.text(value + 0.002, y, " {:.0f}".format(value), color="black", va="center")
            else:  # For zero minutes played, plot a bar at the end of the club name and add "0" label
                club_name = df_single_stat.loc[idx, "Club"]
                club_name_width = ax.text(0, 0, club_name, fontsize=7).get_window_extent(renderer=fig.canvas.get_renderer()).width
                ax.barh(y, 0.001, left=club_name_width + spacing, color="white", edgecolor="black")
                ax.text(club_name_width + 2 * spacing, y, "0", color="black", va="center", ha="left")
        else:
            ax.text(value + spacing, y, " {:.2f}".format(value), color="black", va="center")

    # Move the club name to the left of the plot with some spacing
    club_name = df_single_stat.loc[idx, "Club"]
    ax.text(ax.get_xlim()[0] * 1.5, y, club_name, color="black", va="center", fontsize=7)

ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis="y", length=0)
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide a fully working example along with picture of what you want.

Comment: I can't provide the photo how do I see fixed plot. But I there is link what is wrong with the plot. As you cas see the 0.0 overlapping Clubs names, in this case I need to move this number to the end of the club name

Comment: As the code is missing the part that creates the bars, and doesn't include reproducible test data, it is hard to guess what exactly the code you are showing is doing.  In any case, the code seems to be too complicated for the goal you are describing.